How to Split a string with Key-value pair
I have a list that looks like this:
[ 'abc1234', 'appa4567', 'kkakaka9876']

And I want to split this list, so that every alphabets will become keys and on the right all numeral values.
{ 
    'abc':'1234',
    'appa':'4567',
    'kkakaka':'9876'
}


If you are sure that the strings in the list are always of the same pattern; e.g. lettersDigits, you can do this using built-in regex library re
import re

# Given list of strings
strings = ['abc1234', 'appa4567', 'kkakaka9876']

# Function to split the string using regex
def split_string(s):
    match = re.match(r"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)", s)
    if match:
        return match.groups()

# Convert the list to a dictionary using map and dict comprehension
result = dict(map(split_string, strings))

print(result)

this should result in:
{'abc': '1234', 'appa': '4567', 'kkakaka': '9876'}


Other version using itertools:
from itertools import filterfalse, tee

lst = ["abc1234", "appa4567", "kkakaka9876"]


# from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html
def partition(predicate, iterable):
    """Partition entries into false entries and true entries.

    If *predicate* is slow, consider wrapping it with functools.lru_cache().
    """
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) → 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return filterfalse(predicate, t1), filter(predicate, t2)


out = {}
for s in lst:
    k, v = partition(str.isnumeric, s)
    out["".join(k)] = "".join(v)

print(out)

Prints:
{'abc': '1234', 'appa': '4567', 'kkakaka': '9876'}


OR:
out = dict(map("".join, partition(str.isnumeric, s)) for s in lst)

print(out)


You could use a generator to produce the key/value pairs that can then be passed to dict() as follows:
data = ["abc1234", "appa4567", "kkakaka9876"]

def split(data):
    for item in data:
        for i, c in enumerate(item):
            if c.isdecimal():
                yield item[:i], item[i:]
                break

d = dict(split(data))

print(d)

Output:
{'abc': '1234', 'appa': '4567', 'kkakaka': '9876'}


Well, this is my take on this:
src = ['abc1234', 'appa4567', 'kkakaka9876']
dict((''.join(filter(f, s)) for f in (str.isalpha, str.isdigit)) for s in src)
# {'abc': '1234', 'appa': '4567', 'kkakaka': '9876'}


Just use regx. It will be easy for you.
import re

def split_alphanumeric(lst):
    result = {}
    for item in lst:
        # Use regex to separate alphabetic and numeric parts
        match = re.match(r"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)", item)
        if match:
            alpha_part = match.group(1)
            numeric_part = match.group(2)
            result[alpha_part] = numeric_part
    return result

# Example usage
lst = ['abc1234', 'appa4567', 'kkakaka9876']
split_dict = split_alphanumeric(lst)
print(split_dict)


You can try this simple nested for loop:
Caution : It will only work if you always have keys in alphabet and values in numbers.
if you want, you can modularize and optimize it accordingly

for i in list :
    key = ""
    value = ""
    for j in i : 
        if j.isalpha():
            key += j
        if j.isnumeric():
            value += j
    
    print(key," -> ",value)

    

